# Can infile be used to import a sas log file in a sas program (execution to be done in batch mode ie PuTTY)?

Tags: import, sas, sas-macro

I need to import the errors in a sas log file to a sas dataset(when executed in batch mode i.e. in PuTTY). Is is possible? The code has been included:

```
data test;
    infile  "&l_path/&name..log" truncover;
    input error_and_warning  $2000.;
    if index(_infile_, 'ERROR:') = 1 then output;
    if index(_infile_, 'WARNING:') = 1 then output;
run;
```

Comment: What issues are you having with that code?  Can you post log showing the issue?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code, so either the file has no errors or the file cannot be found/read for some reason.  Given what you've posted we can't verify those issues.

Comment: Be aware you may not be able to read in the log file from the same session that is creating the logfile.

Comment: Hello @RobertPenridge The option suggested by data_null_ is working. I had the same concern as yours, whether a log can be read in the same session. Apparently it can be read.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can read a SAS LOG file just like any other text file.  If you want to read the log of the program that is executing you need to "capture" the log using PROC PRINTTO.

Search at https://lexjansen.com/

I found this 
https://www.mwsug.org/proceedings/2012/S1/MWSUG-2012-S101.pdf

There are many more.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I am able to create a dataset using infile when executed in SAS EG. But when the same code is executed in PuTTY the dataset comes as NULL.

Comment: Perhaps you should show the code and perhaps the log from the data step that reads the log.

Comment: the code is as follow:  data test;
    infile  "&l_path/&name..log" truncover;
    input error_and_warning  $2000.;
    if index(_infile_, 'ERROR:') = 1 then output;
    if index(_infile_, 'WARNING:') = 1 then output;
run;

Comment: Edit your question above with the code you want to show.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the filename "&l_path/&name..log" is correct I think this should have worked.  If there were no errors or warnings data TEST would have zero obs.

```
data test; 
   infile "&l_path/&name..log" truncover; 
   input error_and_warning $2000.; 
   if index(_infile_, 'ERROR:') = 1 then output; 
   if index(_infile_, 'WARNING:') = 1 then output; 
   run;
```

Comment: Note that some error messages have information between the text  `ERROR` in column 1 and the `:` later in the line.

Comment: Yes there are certain errors like syntax error which gives the line numbers as well, but as of now this is a trial code which I want to run in batch mode as well. Can there be issue like "INFILE" automatic variable (for some reason the underscore is not getting reflected in the comment) is not recognized in the UNIX version I am using?

Comment: This code is kept at the end of the program for which the log is being imported. So it is actually taking the log of the program inside the same program. I am not very insightful about  how UNIX works. The creation of log in run-time and importing the same log into the program when executed in UNIX. How possible is that?

Answer (score 1):

I think I've figured the issue you say it works in EG but not batch and that is because the options in batch are different and your data step to scan the log does not execute.  You need to set OBS=MAX and NOSYNTAXCHECK before your data step to scan the log as in this example.

```
1          options generic=1;
2          
3          filename FT12F001 temp;
4          proc printto log=FT12F001;
5             run;

NOTE: PROCEDURE PRINTTO used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds


11         options obs=max syntaxcheck=0;
12         data errbase;
13            infile FT12F001 length=l;
14            input line $varying256. l;
15            if line eq: 'ERROR' then output;
2                                                      The SAS System                     06:17 Wednesday, September 26, 2018

16            putlog _infile_;
17            run;

NOTE: The infile FT12F001 is:
      (system-specific pathname), 
      (system-specific file attributes)

NOTE: PROCEDURE PRINTTO used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds


6          data x;
7             y eq x;
              _
              180
ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.

8             run;

NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
NOTE: SAS set option OBS=0 and will continue to check statements. This might cause NOTE: No observations in data set.
WARNING: The data set WORK.X may be incomplete.  When this step was stopped there were 0 observations and 0 variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.01 seconds
      cpu time            0.01 seconds


9          proc printto;
10            run;
NOTE: 24 records were read from the infile (system-specific pathname).
      The minimum record length was 0.
      The maximum record length was 118.
NOTE: The data set WORK.ERRBASE has 1 observations and 1 variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.01 seconds
      cpu time            0.01 seconds


ERROR: Errors printed on page 1.

NOTE: SAS Institute Inc., SAS Campus Drive, Cary, NC USA 27513-2414
NOTE: The SAS System used:
      real time           3.88 seconds
      cpu time            0.09 seconds
```

Comment: It worked :). Thanks a lot. :) :). Can I ask you how you found the difference in execution for batch mode and EG mode. I having searching for eternity but could not find anything important.

Comment: Start here: https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lesysoptsref&docsetTarget=n014qbvh3po8w5n1qlqbzr22vtg0.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en

Comment: If I had been paying more attention to what you said, I might have figured it sooner.  I rarely use any method of execution other than batch, and forget about the differences.

Comment: Alright.. No problem.. thanks for the solution though.